# Starting Scrapy from a Django view

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, scrapy

My experience with Scrapy is limited, and each time I use it, it's always through the terminal's commands. How can I get my form data (a url to be scraped) from my django template to communicate with scrapy to start doing scraping? So far, I've only thought of is to get the form's returned data from django's views and then try to reach into the spider.py in scrapy's directory to add the form data's url to the spider's start_urls. From there, I don't really know how to trigger the actual crawling since I'm used to doing it strictly through my terminal with commands like "scrapy crawl dmoz". Thanks.

tiny edit: Just discovered scrapyd... I think I may be headed in the right direction with this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've actually answered it with an edit. The best option would be to setup [`scrapyd` service](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and make an API call to [`schedule.json`](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#schedule-json) to trigger a scraping job to run.

To make that API http call, you can either use `urllib2`/`requests`, or use a wrapper around `scrapyd` API - [`python-scrapyd-api`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-scrapyd-api):

```
from scrapyd_api import ScrapydAPI

scrapyd = ScrapydAPI('http://localhost:6800')
scrapyd.schedule('project_name', 'spider_name')
```

---

If we put aside `scrapyd` and try to [run the spider from the view](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script), it will *block the request* until the twisted reactor would stop - therefore, it is not really an option.

You can though, start using [`celery`](http://www.celeryproject.org/) (in tandem with [`django_celery`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery)) - define a task that would run your Scrapy spider and call the task from your django view. This way, you would *put the task on the queue* and would not have a user waiting for crawling to be finished.

---

Also, take a look at the [django-dynamic-scraper](https://django-dynamic-scraper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) package:

> Django Dynamic Scraper (DDS) is an app for Django build on top of the
>   scraping framework Scrapy. While preserving many of the features of
>   Scrapy it lets you dynamically create and manage spiders via the
>   Django admin interface.

Comment: Would you know anything about how to actually setup the file structure of scrapy within a django project? Can I just put my scrapy folder inisde my django project folder? Or is there more to it? Thanks.

Comment: Also, wouldn't scrapyd do the same thing as celery in regards to handling the crawl asyncronously?

Comment: @pyramidface speaking about the project structure - I've never personally combined django and scrapy in a single project, but used both products extensively - try looking at `django-dynamic-scraper` and the examples it has closely - may be you would get an idea on how to combine both tools in a single project. Or, start a new SO question, but be careful to make it constructive.

Comment: @pyramidface `scrapyd` vs `celery` is more like apples and oranges, two different options for your use case. I would still stick to `scrapyd` as it is a very specialized tool for web-scraping and has a nice interface. Besides, by calling `scrapyd` API to start a job - you would know if there are any problems at this point, while `celery` would encounter it too late, at the step of firing up twisted with scrapy on board.

Comment: Yay! Got my web-scraping silver badge! :)

Comment: Just for whoever visits this question with a similar goal in mind, I was not able to get python-scrapyd-api to accept a start_urls parameter, and I don't think it actually supports it right now. What I did instead was superclass my spider so that it actually requires a url when you curl it and then use requests to post to scrapyd with the url

Comment: My two cents: DDS is a very nice project, but I feel some lack of flexibility when configuring spiders inside. Is great to use models to store items directly and celery integration, but if your target is not very simple or require several request to get to the bacon, it may become painfull. Maybe I am missing something?. I will try to use my own spiders within DDS [not admin site configured] hoping that still make sense. otherwise  my next project will be scrapyd-celery for sure.