# Run Scrapy through Django View

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

So, I am working on the following project:
I am using `Django` to develop a website that will work as a remote manager of a web crawler. To be more specific, I've created a spider with `Scrapy` that downloads some PDF files from another website.
My goal is to find a way to call the spider via a `POST` (I guess) request and have the crawler running through my `Django` view. The files that are downloaded will be stored to the server that has the website running, not to the personal computer of anyone who runs the spider.
So when I log into my website and press the `Crawl` button, the new files get downloaded into the server's file library.

I am fairly new to Django and Scrapy so I have no clue how to make them work together to achieve what I am looking for, can someone guide me to a direction?
I've seen some questions regarding running `Scrapy` scripts through other `Python` scripts but I do not understand how to connect them, where to put the `Scrapy` project files etc.

Thank you for your time, I hope I didn't confuse you!

Comment: similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921879/starting-scrapy-from-a-django-view

Comment: To be honest I've checked that post and couldn't understand how `Scrapyd` works so I wanted to ask if anyone has experience with a similar situation to guide me someway! I'll check it again tho, thank you!

Comment: For everyone wondering the same, Scrapyd ended up working like a charm for me. I had some trouble figuring it out but I'd be glad to help anyone who has the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend start a new process inside your django view, in this case i would use a job queue like redis queue, you can easy configure using `django-rq`.
https://github.com/rq/django-rq

Then you can enqueue the spider and run in a worker.

```
import django_rq

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from my_project.spider import MySpider

def run_spider():
    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    process.crawl(MySpider)
    process.start()

django_rq.enqueue(run_spider)
```